# iPhone-link Sync in Apple Mail

Tags: iphone, email, osx-snow-leopard, sync, imap

Is it possible to setup an iPhone-like sync with Mail on Snow Leopard? Currently it downloads all 18000 messages from Gmail (IMAP) and when I delete a messages, it isn't deleted from Gmail.

Can someone post steps for this type of (iPhone-like) configuration? Or any tutorial available?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you setup your Mail to Gmail through the IMAP protocol, any change from your desktop Mail will be mirrored to the Gmail at the server side.

See the official setup tutorial from [Apple Mail 3.0 (Leopard) - Gmail Help](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81379)

Comment: Its already setup using IMAP, but still it does NOT work like the iPhone

Comment: You've tried to remove the gmail account and re-add it, right?